# how to repeat a loop a certain number of times to get the Nth derivative?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, polynomials, derivative

I am trying to get the Nth derivative for coefficients and powers of a polynomial equation given in a dictionary. In the dictionary, the key is the power and the value is the coefficient of the given polynomial.

Here is my code, that works for a first order derivative:

'''

```
def differentiate(polynomial, order):

        derivative = {}

        for power, coeff in poly.items():

            new_coeff = poly[power] * power

            new_power = power - 1

            derivative[new_power] = new_coeff

            if derivative[new_power] == 0:

                del derivative[new_power]

        return derivative

if __name__ == "__main__":  
        poly = {-5: 4.0, 2: 3.5, 1: 10.0}
        print(differentiate(poly, 2))  # {-7: 120.0, 0: 7.0}
```

'''

How would I repeat the loop to get a derivative of Nth order?
I tried to use the range function but I can't seem to make it work.
Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed this

```
def differentiate(polynomial, order):
    derivative = {}
    counter = 1
    _dict = polynomial

    while counter <= order:
        for power, coeff in _dict.items():
            new_coeff = _dict[power] * power
            new_power = power - 1
            derivative[new_power] = new_coeff
            if derivative[new_power] == 0:
                del derivative[new_power]
        counter += 1
        _dict = derivative
        derivative = {}
    return _dict
```

Comment: oh I think it works ! thanks a lot !!